# Is it possible to design my own Database GUI?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I have made a java application to store information but i don't want to use MySql or Oracle interface instead i want to make my own GUI which is easier to interact is it possible somehow? if so how?

Comment: sorry but you question is way too broad for stack overflow. Please read [ask] and re-formulate with a concrete problem.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha I just need suggestions for instance the name of softwares/technique i'll work else out myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you do not have a lot of experience in database engine implementation, I would strongly recommend using PostgreSQL as your starting point. PostgreSQL is the most competently engineered of the open source database engines, it is designed to be extremely hackable, and it is well-documented and widely used. Many (most?) commercial analytical databases are actually based on the PostgreSQL code base so there is relatively little that can't be done using it with some effort.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in Java land, you could use something like JavaFX for the GUI work.

I would read about MVC (model, view, controller) architecture too.